# Saving data in localstorage upon close?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get values saved in `localStorage` so that they can persist when the user comes back to the site.  Here is what I have:

```js
function saveConfirmation() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to exit? Progress will be saved.")) {
        localStorage.setItem("count", String(count))
    }
}
function saveBeforeUnload() {
    setTimeout(saveConfirmation, 0)
    return "You have unsaved changes"
}

window.onbeforeunload = saveBeforeUnload
```

When I click out of the tab, Chrome gives a popup asking if I want to leave the page.  When I say yes, my other dialogue comes up right as it closes so I can't interact with it.  If I say no, my other dialogue comes up and doesn't close when I confirm. 
How do I get it to where it either:

1. Saves when I confirm the popup from Chrome or
2. Gets rid of the Chrome popup and save and exit when I confirm my popup?

Comment: That's a very interesting question, and I'd be very curious to know the answer. Isn't it a better practice to save things as they come though?

Comment: That is something I considered, but with how my project is set up, the aforementioned count I am saving is constantly updated and will get into very large numbers (upwards of 10e30) so I'm not sure if it is better to do that, or just when the user leaves the page so that it's there when they come back